# char e construtores em c++

Tags: array, c++, construtor, char

Preciso de um construtor para uma classe que possui vetores de char como atributos, como essa:

```
class Anthem {
    private:
        int Id;
        char Name[50];
        char Country[50];
        int Year;
        char Composer[30];
        char Historic[200];
    public:
        Anthem(int id, char name[50], char country[50], int year, char 
composer[30], char historic[200]);
        ~Anthem();
}
```

Mas não sei como deve ficar no construtor de fato, fiz assim:

```
Anthem::Anthem(int id, char* name, char* country, int year, char* composer, 
char* historic) { // @suppress("Class members should be properly initialized")
    Id = id;
    Name = name;
    Country = country;
    Year = year;
    Composer = composer;
    Historic = historic;
}
```

Mas não da certo, como devo fazer?

Comment: Porque não simplificar e utilizar `std::string` já que é c++ ?

Comment: @Isac ah, pq simplificar se pode complicar? :P

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa usar

```
Name[] = name;
assert( strlen( Name) < sizeof( name) );
strcpy( name, Name );
```

ao invés de

```
Name = name;
```

Veja [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422487/how-can-i-initialize-char-arrays-in-a-constructor);